# Node.js ENOENT Reading PDF file

Tags: node.js, pdf, enoent

I need to read pdf file and I use `pdf-text-extract`. It works perfectly on my localhost. But when I tried to run the program on server, I got the following error

```
spawn called
{ '0': 'pdftotext',
  '1': 
   [ '-layout',
     '-enc',
     'UTF-8',
     '/tmp/the_file_name.pdf',
     '-' ],
  '2': { encoding: 'UTF-8', layout: 'layout', splitPages: true } }

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: spawn ENOENT
  at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)
```

Here is how I use `pdf-text-extract`

```
var extract = require('pdf-text-extract');

.....

.then (function () {
  console.log(fs.readdirSync('/tmp'));
  var extractAsync = Promise.promisify(extract);
  return extractAsync(filePath);
})
.catch (function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

As you can see, I have added catch, but why the error is Unhandled 'error' event.

I have also checked that the file is exist using `fs.readdirSync`. What cause the error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Your server does not have the `pdftotext` command, which the `pdf-text-extract` module tries to spawn as a child process. The readme for the module includes [a link](https://github.com/nisaacson/pdf-extract) to how to install the program for various platforms.